# JMeter to run more than one test plan at the same command

Tags: jmeter

Is it applicable to run JMeter command with more than one test plan ?

```
jmeter -n -t /path to the script.jmx
```

Currently, I need to run the same test plan more than once at the same time

Answer (score 0):

To run the **same test plan more than once at the same time**, you have to configure **master-slave** environments.

In **Distributed/Remote Environment**, it's possible to run the same test scripts from multiple machines at the same time.

For details, see [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

Comment: Are we able to run both master and slave at the same time?